# Typesense cloud restart unhealthy cluster

Tags: typesense

I made some tests in my Typesense-Cloud cluster to see where are the limits from Typesense and what will happen in that case. However, I reached that limit already and now the cluster has the state “Unhealthy” since around 2h, and it seems like the cluster will not restart. So, my question is, do we have a way to restart our cluster by ourselves, or do I need to delete my “Test-Cluster” now?

Configurations:

- Typesense v0.23.1
- 0.5 GB RAM
- 2 vCPUs, 1hr burst per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to restart a cluster in Typesense Cloud. However, even if there was a way to do this, once you've exhausted RAM capacity, restarting will not fix the issue because on restart the data will be re-indexed in RAM and the cluster will become unhealthy once again.

So the solution would be to upgrade your cluster to the next RAM tier. If you don't have automatic capacity upgrades enabled for the cluster, you should have received an email notification from support asking for your permission to upgrade you. You want to respond to that notification to stabilize the cluster.